# Python 3 calendar. Мне нужно генерировать вертикальный html календарь

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, datetime

На питоне нужно реализовать [вертикальный календарь](http://3mu.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/calendar-2019-ver-dni.png) в HTML формате. Использую [calendar](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/calendar.html) библиотеку. Пришел к выводу, что нужно переписать методы класса HTMLCalendar, и хотел бы посоветоваться о возможных вариантах. Вариант, до которого додумался я - написать свои методы для каждого дня недели, и заполнять месяцы по ним.(т.е. сначала все понедельники месяца, потом вторники и т.д до воскресения) Но хочется верить, что есть более умный способ.

Comment: Можно вопрос? Почему календарь нужен именно на питоне?Чем плох bootstrap?Вот неплохой календарь https://codepen.io/hind-jai/pen/GaxmYP

Comment: Мне нужна возможность прикрепления событий ко дню(что-то вроде ежедневника). Для этого был выбран django framework, отсюда и python. Там реализовать это достаточно просто в плане backend-а. И вот мне осталось только разобраться как сделать вертикальный календарь.

Comment: @Naur Всё решается шаблонизатором и библиотекой datetime. Лучше бы поподробнее описали, чего не получается. Вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: Например по науке и с современными  трендами в веб сделать бы календарь с ajax - когда Вы json плюете в фронтэнд, а он сам отрисовывает указанный Вами контент со всеми плюшками. Еще и стили с динамикой размера под разные высоты экрана получаются как надо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переписал пару методов и получил то, что нужно

```
class Vertical(HTMLCalendar):

    def formatweekrow(self, theweeks, daynum):
        """
        Return a complete week as a table row.
        """
        v = []
        s = v.append
        s('<tr>')
        for theweek in theweeks:
            for (d, wd) in theweek:
                if wd == daynum:
                    s(self.formatday(d, wd))
        s('</tr>')
        return ''.join(v)

    def formatmonth(self, theyear, themonth, withyear=True):
        """
        Return a formatted month as a table.
        """
        cnt = 0
        v = []
        theweeks = self.monthdays2calendar(theyear, themonth)
        a = v.append
        a('<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="">')
        a('\n')
        a(self.formatmonthname(theyear, themonth, withyear=withyear))
        a('\n')
        a(self.formatweekheader())
        a('\n')
        while cnt < 7:
            a(self.formatweekrow(theweeks, cnt))
            a('\n')
            cnt += 1
        a('</table>')
        a('\n')
        return ''.join(v)
```

Comment: Ваш код не будет работать.

Comment: Ну он уже работает, но может быть я чего-то не учел. Не могли бы вы рассказать где он ломается?

Comment: Потому что в python отступы решают многое.

Comment: Копировал изначально рабочий код, не обратил при вставке внимания.